# how to organize big conditional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have to create array with a lot of conditions. but when i try to read that what i wrote it's very complicated to know what i'm try to doing. so i try to simplify to this conditions but nothing comes to my mind. placements are important too. how can i simplify this code block?

```
const createArrayByConditions =
 (condition1, condition2, condition3, condition4) => {

  if (condition1) {
   if (condition4) {
    return [
     1, 4, 999,
    ];
   } else {
    return [1, 999];
   }
  }

  if (condition2) {
   if (condition4) {
    return [
     2, 4, 999,
    ];
   }
   return [2, 999];
  }

  if (condition3) {
   if (condition4) {
    return [
     3, 4, 999,
    ];
   } else {
    return [3, 999];
   }
  }

  if (condition4) {
   return [4, 999];
  } else {
   return [999];
  }
 };
```

Comment: Once a function returns it's terminated. You'll always have `[1, 4, 999]`

Comment: yes, thats what i want, you can think it's a mock conditions data

Comment: The rest of the function never happens, so remove that and I'd say it's a lot less complicated congrats

Comment: @ryoshpa it's not clear if you are willing to simplify the exact code you wrote.. or if that code has some parameters that you wish to change at some point and still have the function working. For example those condition are hardcoded like that? or you wish to change it like they were function arguments... ok now that you changed the question is more clear

Answer (score 3):

A fairly clean solution comes to mind. It seems that the return array always contains `999`, so we start with an array with just that value. `4` is also always included as long as `condition4` is truthy. Lastly we need to prefix `1`, `2`, or `3`, based on which conditionN evaluates as a truthy value first.

```js
function createArrayByConditions(
  condition1, condition2, condition3, condition4
) {
  const array = [999];
  
  if (condition4) array.unshift(4);
  
  if      (condition1) array.unshift(1);
  else if (condition2) array.unshift(2);
  else if (condition3) array.unshift(3);
  
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Overall it seems like there is nothing to simplify. You have your conditions and the complexity is there. If you can't make more assumptions on the returned values (they are examples, I assume), then you are good with what you have.

I personally prefer ternary operators if every conditional path eventually returns a value of the same type. But I know you can easily shoot yourself in the foot with them. However, you may decide on the readability:

```js
const createArrayByConditions = (c1, c2, c3, c4) => c1
  ? (c4 ? [1, 4, 999] : [1, 999])
  : c2
  ? (c4 ? [2, 4, 999] : [2, 999])
  : c3
  ? (c4 ? [3, 4, 999] : [3, 999])
  : (c4 ? [4, 999] : [999]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the furthest I could simplify the conditions by looping the arguments passed as an array:

```js
const createArrayByConditions =
 (conditions) => {
  for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    if ( conditions[i] && conditions[3] ){
      return [i+1, 4, 999]
    }
    else if( conditions[i] ){
      return [i+1, 999];
    }
  }  
  if(conditions[3])
    return [4, 999];
  else
    return [999];
 };

 //1-4
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([true, false, false, false]) );   //-> [1,999]
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([true, false, false, true]) );    //-> [1,4,999]

 //2-4
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([false, true, false, false]) );   //-> [2,999]
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([false, true, false, true]) );    //-> [2,4,999]

 //3-4
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([false, false, true, false]) );   //-> [3,999]
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([false, false, true, true]) );    //-> [3,4,999]
 
 //4
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([false, false, false, true]) );   //-> [4,999]
 console.log( createArrayByConditions([false, false, false, false]) );  //-> [999]
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve readability you can do:

```
const createArrayByConditions = (
  condition1,
  condition2,
  condition3,
  condition4
) => {
  switch (true) {
    case condition1:
      return condition4 ? [1, 4, 999] : [1, 999];

    case condition2:
      return condition4 ? [2, 4, 999] : [2, 999];

    case condition3:
      return condition4 ? [3, 4, 999] : [3, 999];

    case condition4:
      return [4, 999];

    default:
      return [999];
  }
};
```

Comment: i edited my question to be more clear, sorry about that

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. Improved answer